# Remove song from iTunes playlist based on tab-separated list

Tags: applescript, itunes

How can I use Applescript to remove any songs from myPlaylist if they contain one of the names + artists + years contained in a tab-separated file?

So if track one of myPlaylist is:

'Greensleeves    The Scorpions    1965'

and the tab-separated text file contains the line:

Greensleeves    The Scorpions   1965

It will delete the track from the playlist. Also, it needs to be the exact title, because some of my song titles have brackets and odd characters in them.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get on with the script I submitted in my answer ?  I know I didn't add any blurb with it, but of course, there wasn't a whole lot to say except for the script should do what you asked.  If there are any issues with it, let me know and I can fix them.  I'll await your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use application "iTunes"
use scripting additions
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
###USER-DEFINED PROPERTIES: path, playlist
property path : "~/Desktop/trackdelete.list"
property playlist : "myPlaylist"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
property text item delimiters : tab
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
###IMPLEMENTATION
#
#
tell the deleteList
    if not (its file exists) then return -1

    read

    repeat with i from 1 to the length of its list
        set [its name, its artist, its year] to ¬
            [text item 1, text item 2, text item 3] of ¬
            item i of its list

        delete (playlistItem's track where ¬
            name = deleteList's name and ¬
            artist = deleteList's artist and ¬
            year = deleteList's year)
    end repeat
end tell
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
###SCRIPT OBJECTS & HANDLERS
#
#
script playlistItem
    property playlist : a reference to the playlist named (my playlist)
    property track : a reference to every track of my playlist
end script

script deleteList
    property application : application "System Events"
    property file : a reference to file (my path) of my application
    property list : null
    property name : null
    property artist : null
    property year : null

    to read
        tell AppleScript to read (my file as alias)
        set my list to the result's paragraphs
    end read
end script
---------------------------------------------------------------------------❮END❯
```

***System info:*** *AppleScript version*: "2.7", *system version*: "10.13.6"

Comment: OK, I guess this has to be pasted into Terminal? I did that, changing the properties to 

property path : "Macintosh\ HD/Applications/Automator\ stuff/01b\ iTunes\ Scripts/SL+.txt”
property playlist : “Test1”

But I get what I think is an error message: -bash: tell: command not found
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `its'

Comment: No, why did you think it has to be pasted into _Terminal_ ?  You asked for an AppleScript - so I gave you an AppleScript.  Paste it into _Script Editor_.  And don't escape spaces in the `path` property.

Comment: OK, sorry, it was because I'd never seen the command 'use application' before. I will try again now!

Comment: So I get this message now: 'exists file "Macintosh HD/Applications/Automator stuff/01b iTunes Scripts/SL+.txt"
  --> false'
But it's a plain text document and according to finder it is in that location. See: 'Where: /Applications/Automator stuff/01b iTunes Scripts'

Comment: OK, just tried it WITHOUT the 'Macintosh HD' and it worked a treat. Thanks! Appreciate your help and your quick reply to me before.